# Create albums from folders / remove duplicates

Tags: google-photos

I am using Google Photos to backup my old photos. Using the mac desktop uploader. 
I have an external hard drive with folders in the following format:

```
|
+- 2005
  +---Wedding
  +---Trip to france
  +---Bachelor party
+- 2006
  +---Work travel to Japan
  +---etc
+etc..
```

I want google photos to automatically create the albums according to folder names. Is that possible? How?

Also I got a bunch of duplicates on google photos - is there any tool to clean those?

I've found this question: 
[Create albums on Google Photos from folders of photos on local disk](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/78552/create-albums-on-google-photos-from-folders-of-photos-on-local-disk)
- but the answers talk about Picasa which has been retired so its no longer relevant or possible.

Comment: This question includes two questions, but look that you only searched for one of the them, the one about folders. On this sites there are also questions regarding the duplicates. I think that you should remove the question about duplicates and perhaps post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

> I want google photos to automatically create the albums according to folder names. Is that possible? How?

Albums can't include other albums, no it's not possible to replicate a hierarchical folder structure as albums.

One alternative is to use Google Drive for PC/Mac as it will sync the folder structure.

Another alternative is to upload the folders to Google Drive through the http://drive.google.com by uploading your folders to My Drive or to a previously created folder.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently created and released a desktop application that does exactly that: http://jiotty-photos-uploader.yudichev.net. It's free, open source and works in  all popular operating systems. A summary of what it does is extracted from the project wiki:

> Jiotty Photos Uploader is a simple desktop application for Windows, macOS and Linux that scans a folder, including all subfolders, for photos and videos, and uploads them to your Google Photos gallery arranging into albums according to the directory structure.
>
> When creating albums, each album name is composed of all the intermediate folders in the hierarchy, separated by colon. For example, the following structure:

```
Folder1
     photo1.jpg
     Folder2
        video1.mov     
photo2.jpg
```

> will result in this layout in your Google Photos gallery:

```
Media item | Will be uploaded to album 
==========================================
photo1.jpg | Folder1
photo2.jpg | Will not be added to any album 
video1.mov | Folder1: Folder2
```

> The app is able to resume where it left off, so it will not attempt to re-upload all those photos and videos it already uploaded, unless you ask it to.

Comment: Excellent work and great documentation!